# How to look check whether model exists and create if it doesn't with a single form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I'm trying to implement a form with the following behavior:

1) Input some semantic data about a user (i.e. username).
2) Do a User.find_by(:username = username).
3) If such a user exists, direct to show page for that user.
4) If such a user does not exist, create a new user with the provided username, then redirect to the show page for that user.

This should be simple but I cannot figure out how to format the form_for helper and my show and create actions in my user_controller to implement this behavior.

I currently have:

form_with :url => 'users/:id', :method => :get do
...
end

because I'm ultimately trying to invoke the "show" method of the controller. However, my form does not take in a user's id as a parameter, and when the user does not yet exist there is no :id parameter to access at the time of the form's submission.

How can I set up my form to redirect to show in each case, while still adhering to the logic explained above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your User's Controller create action

```
def create
  usr_name = params[:username]
  @user = User.where(username: usr_name).first_or_initialize

  if @user.persisted?
    redirect_to user_path(@user) # or whatever your user show path is
  elsif @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user) 
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You would just need to make sure that you are validating the uniqueness of usernames.

Also, `first_or_initialize`(and its counterpart `first_or_create`) can take in a block. So, you can assign other attributes to the new User like this...

```
User.where(username: usr_name).first_or_initialize do |usr|
  usr.some_attribute = some_value
end
```

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that the "create" function is reserved conventionally for posting a new record to a database, whereas the "show" function is used to get an existing record. Ideally I'd be able to structure my code to respect these conventions, for better integration with the rest of the application.

Comment: This respects those conventions. Checking to see if a user exists before creating it is part of your create logic...

Answer (score 0):

you can use find_or_initialize_by(unique_key) in your create method.unique_key can be any key which you are using to identify your user such as email,phone etc.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I wanted to search by a combination of keys which are not each unique, but unique as a collection?

Comment: you can use more than 1 attributes in find_or_initialize_by. just check here https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by